# Embed windows media player in HTML web page with playlist feature

Tags: html

I want to embed an audio player into my web page with a playlist feature.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, clean way of doing it via Jquery (one of many options out there):  http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/

The (somewhat clunky) Microsoft way of doing it: http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed.html

Using an audio player that's not proprietary is good UI practice.  For instance, Flash isn't available on all user's computers.  WMV (which the windows example uses) is a very windows-centric format, and may not be supported to some linux or mac users.  Many people don't run quick time, so the AAC format might not be a great format to embed.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [Windows Media Metafiles](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/introwmmeta.aspx).